# Suspicious Conversation

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

Yesterday, I overheard the conversation between my friends Jim and Rose:

> **Jim**: I know lots of games.
>
> **Rose**: Wow, let's play some.
>
> **Jim**: If Jack too was here, it would have been great fun.
>
> **Rose**: Oh, I miss Jack a lot.
>
> **Jim**: He came last week for the exams.
>
> **Rose**: Ha! Really? He didn't tell me.
>
> **Jim**: He asked for a tea party.
>
> **Rose**: Yes, it should be arranged.
>
> **Jim**: Let's go at 4:00pm. He must be at home at that time.
>
> **Rose**: He has nailed the exams and so he should be hosting the
>   party, right?
>
> **Jim**: Yup, and I bought a pen for him to appreciate his success in the
>   exams.
>
> **Rose**: Oh, great. Let me see it.
>
> **Jim**: Aha, you lost. I am the winner.

What game they were playing? How did Rose lose and Jim win? And how does this conversation make sense?

Comment: Is "It Jack too was here" correct or did you mean "If Jack..."?

Comment: Is "the one who hosting" correct?

Comment: Yes. It's "if". I have edited it. Thank you for pointing it out. :)

Comment: @AE: It is correct. Any how I have edited the question to avoid confusions.

Comment: OK. Should "appreciate his success" be "congratulate him on his success" or similar?

Comment: Yes. That will fit.

Comment: I think of some games like "don't say you,me, and he/she" in Chinese. We start a meaningless conversation and someone who speaks a forbidden word lose the game

Comment: @autodavid The only word that could lead to it is `see`

Comment: is it like they playing for opposite words?for e.g jack missing-he present like wise?

Comment: There may be a third person in the conversation, whose lines have been edited out.

Comment: Does this game have a real name?  If you wanted to play this game, you would say, "I assume you want play the ___ game with me?"  (ass)

Comment: May be "disguised animals" game :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I thought that it was

> animals formed by consecutive letters in the sentence

and it turns out that's correct.

```
Jim: I know lots of games.
```

> owl

```
Rose: Wow, let's play some.
```

> owl also (edited to say: probably owlet)

```
Jim: If Jack too was here, it would have been great fun.
```

> bee

```
Rose: Oh, I miss Jack a lot.
```

> jackal

```
Jim: He came last week for the exams.
```

> camel

```
Rose: Ha! Really? He didn't tell me.
```

> hare

```
Jim: He asked for a tea party.
```

> rat

```
Rose: Yes, it should be arranged.
```

> bear

```
Jim: Let's go at 4:00pm. He must be at home at that time.
```

> goat

```
Rose: He has nailed the exams and so he should be hosting the party, right?
```

> snail

```
Jim: Yup, and I bought a pen for him to appreciate his success in the exams.
```

> edited to add: ape (thanks to f' in the comments)

```
Rose: Oh, great. Let me see it.
```

> And here's where Rose lost, since she had no animal.

```
Jim: Aha, you lost. I am the winner.
```

Comment: There's "ape" in Jim's statement (bought **a pe**n).

Comment: Perfect. Please add what  @f'' suggested to make the answer complete and I will accept the answer :)

Answer (score 8):

My first attempt:

> Jim and Rose has already starting the game the moment the conversation starts, and the rule is to continue the conversation in a way that, when reading backward, it makes sense.  They were both doing fine until Rose's last sentence, which loses her the game.

Comment: That definitely seems like it - nice find!

Comment: Nice finding. But there is a better fit than that.